# Overlapping menu tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a new website project which is for hospital I have done everything but I am having problems in menu which looks simple but it is very complicated..

The problem is that the menu tabs are overlapping each other which i did achieved that by floating the ul and after giving the minus margins it is perfectly overlapping but the thing which iam not able to achieve is that wen a tab is clicked it should change its background image to a new background image (from blue color image to green color image) and should be popped up and by default the homepage should be selected.

Any advice or guidance on how to achieve or do this menu in a correct or proper order will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to create a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: @ Roberto Aloi thanks for prompt response but i dont know how to use jsfiddle what i did is actually pasted the html and css in there but i dont know what to do next......i have a png image of the menu which i want to share but i dont have that much points to share it here..is there any other way :(

Comment: @user614235 Next you need to press the "Save" button. JS Fiddle generates a custom URL which you can share with us by pressing the "Share" button.

Comment: For the background changes there are many ways of doing this. Like using events when triggers will just change its background. Our concern is you need to work on your code and show us which part of it causing you problem. It may easy for us to help you if we can see your code.

Comment: @DADU thankyou for the info  @ ace here is the links for the menu which i created as a fiddle..."http://jsfiddle.net/user614235/zpcEt/"... is there any way i can share u the png image for the overlapping menu...

Comment: Which do you mean your clicking? Is it the menu that overlap? Well as I inspect it in firebug and chrome development tools. Your menu tab cannot be click and only the image can do the events of onClick. Because the position of your menu is not visible to mouse pointer. Is my observation is correct?

Answer (score 0):

check this web link as I think it will solve your problem and I hope this helps you .....

[create-a-smooth-tabbed-menu-in-jquery](http://yensdesign.com/2008/12/create-a-smooth-tabbed-menu-in-jquery/)